# Same Endpoint for three different operations using GET RequestMethod in REST

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-mvc

I want to have the same Endpoint for three different operations in one Request Method type as GET in REST Controller in Spring MVC application.

For example three operations GET Request Method:1 . ListofItems, 2. LoadDropdown,3. searchoneParticularItem.

Endpoint 1:/items this end point I could use it to list the items
Endpoint 2:/items/{itemId} this endpoint I could use it to search particular object.

How can I get the third operation load the drop downs of items?

Please give me some example to have atleast three operations in GET with same Endpoint.

Comment: Are you talking about 3 different @RequestMappings on same controller action?

Comment: Yes the same controller should have 3 GET Request Mapping with different operations

Answer (score 0):

It takes String[] in value, it can handle multiple urls, use

```
@RequestParam(value=["mapping1","mapping2","mappping3"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`@RequestMapping` `value` attribute takes `String[]`, so you can map multiple URLs to the same controller method as shown below:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/listItems", "/dropdownItems", 
    "/items/{itemId}"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loadItems(@PathVariable String item, Model model) {
       //add items to model
       //return JSP or HTML
    }
```

You can refer [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html)

Comment: Yes, but we have different Object to be returned For example /items needs to return the list of Item object for /items/iteamId needs to return an Item Object. How could this single Controller method return different Object?